# Why doesn't New 52 Earth 2 Batman have a no gun policy?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, the-new-52

I'm basing my question on this specific extract from World's Finest #20 (New 52) :

[image]

In this page, Huntress (Earth 2 Batman and Catwoman daughter), at this moment with Prime Earth Batman (the main one), is surprised that his Batplane doesn't have any cannon, contrary to her father's, implying that Earth 2 version of Batman doesn't seem to be bothered by using guns. Why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Earth-Two is [DC’s home for the “Golden Age” heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Two?wprov=sfti1) from the 1930-50s.
That era’s Batman (and Robin) did not have a problem with using guns or killing criminals.
This blog post has a [detailed history of Batman and guns.](http://sacomics.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/batman-and-guns.html?m=1)